# meta-search/ransack for mongoid

Tags: mongoid, meta-search

I was just wondering if anyone has come across anything offering similar search functionality for mongoid as meta-search/ransack? During my searches I came across this [mongoid group thread](http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/tree/browse_frm/thread/dc30733e1d1e90f3/9cad828df099c1af?hide_quotes=no/) which mentioned sunspot_mongoid. I only had a quick look at it but my impression is that it doesn't quite offer the same view level helpers as meta-search which is really  what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no project actually to do the same than `meta_search` on Mongoid gem. But there are a open issue about support Mongoid on `meta_search` maybe you can follow it.

About sunspot_mongoid it's a gem to wrap your Mongoid to a solr search engine. It's really not related to job do by `meta_search`

There are no feature request about support Mongoid on `ransack`.